# Javascript / jQuery search for letter in string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, search, letter

I'm using JS / jQuery (new to jQuery) and I have a string with a math problem in it, including a variable. (I'm creating a function to solve basic algebra). ie:

```
var $problem = "x+5=11";
// Take off any whitespace from user input
$problem = $problem.replace(/\s+/g,"");
// Split problem into two parts
$problem = $problem.split("=");
```

Now I need to determine which part contains the variable.
In this example it would be

```
$problem[0] // This stores "x+5"
```

What i'm stuck at is that the variable could be any letter, not just x, so I can't just search for x. It could be: a, b, A, x, z, Y.

Comment: you need to test for regex `/[a-zA-Z]+/`

Comment: I hate regex :( It confuses me. But if it's my only option, I must use it!

Comment: what  do you want to do with `x+5`? probably you want separate it further to `x` and `5` again

Comment: @ArunPJohny Yeah, I have the steps for the function written down on paper, that's the next step after determining which part of the array has the variable. For example, I don't event want to try to split the 11 into another array because it only has the one number.

Comment: So you want to check whether LHS or RHS has a variable right?

Comment: @AJ Yes. I know how to check if the variable was 'x' all the time, but since it's based on user input, the variable can change.

Comment: that means first you need to find out whether the LHS/RHS has a variable. it can be done via a simple regex test `/[a-zA-Z]+/.test($problem[0])`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can test for any variable which has an alphabet using the regex

```
if(/[a-zA-Z$][a-zA-Z$_0-9]*/.test($problem[0])){
    //left part has a variable
}
```

Comment: common algebra variable names can contain digits too

Comment: @Ejay in that case we can improve the regex

Comment: @Ejay in js i think vairables can start with an alphabet or `$`

Comment: that's more like programming language variable naming conventions :) He's talking about algebra

Answer (score 0):

```
'x+5'.split(/[\W]+/g)

'xyx-2a*yb+5'.split(/[\W]+/g)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can check if a string has a alphabet in it or not as following:

```
    var str = "x+1";
    if (str.match(/[a-zA-Z]/g)) {
        alert("true");
        }
    else {

        alert("false");
    }
```

Hope this helps!